# Diferença de dias javascript considerando datas em meses diferentes

Tags: javascript

Preciso pegar a diferença entre duas datas.
Porem, na minha regra de negócio, a diferença das 17/05/2014 e 17/05/2014 é de 1 dia.
Então pensei que apenas adicionando um dia no resultado final resolveria meu problema.
Porem, quando peço o intervalo de (por exemplo) 30/09/2014 para 01/10/2014 ele me retorna o resultado esperado. 2 dias.
Se eu pedir de 30 a 30, ele me retorna 0.

#### Script atual:

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/')
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[1], mdy[0]-1);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    var date1 = parseDate(first);
    var date2 = parseDate(second);
    return (date2-date1)/(1000*60*60*24) + 1;
}
```

Por que acontece isso e como ajustar essa comparação de diferenças para o meu caso?

Comment: Testei no Chrome e o resultado foi o esperado. Pode ser problema de arredondamento no seu browser. Tente colocar: `return Math.ceil(date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 *24)) + 1;`

Comment: Uma palavra: [Moment](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, se voce testar 30/09/2014 para 01/10/2014, o resultado retornado será 3 dias.  :/

Comment: Só verifica uma coisa: o parâmetro `month` vai de 0 a 11. Teria que diminuir 1 do mês na construção do objeto (2º parâmetro)

Comment: E se o mes for 0? :)  De qualquer maneira, se observar a funcao parseDate, ela já se encarrega disso.

Comment: Mas o terceiro parâmetro não é o dia?

Comment: As datas entram em daydiff com formato br: dd/mm/yyy. E então, ele aciona o parseDate para delimitar a string e criar uma nova data.

Comment: Testei de varias formas aqui. E o que parece, é que existe realmente essa inconsistência no calculo de datas.

Comment: O mesmo script com os mesmos cálculos em php funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: @rrnan.. Valeu. Resolvi utilizando o moment.js

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz posta a sua solução como resposta, explicando com utilizou e qual foi o resultado. Isso pode ajudar futuras perguntas sobre o mesmo assunto. :)

Answer (score 1):

Montei esta função com base em pesquisas.
Creio ser melhor que usar uma biblioteca, pois ai você vai direto ao ponto não fica carregando recursos a mais, contudo ela é um tando restritiva, teria de se adaptar.

```
function betweenDates(d1, d2, diff, returnLiteral){

    d1      = d1.split(' ');    // Divide o timestamp em data e hora
    d1[0]   = d1[0].split('-'); // Separa as variacoes da data
    d1[1]   = d1[1].split(':'); // Separa as variacoes da hora
    d1      = d1[0].concat(d1[1]); // concatena os dois conteudos formando um array unico.

    d1 = new Date(d1[0],d1[1],d1[2],d1[3],d1[4],d1[5]); // gera o objeto date
    d1 = Date.UTC(d1.getFullYear(), d1.getMonth(), d1.getDate(), d1.getHours(), d1.getMinutes(), d1.getSeconds()); // retona o time UTC corespondente da data.

    d2      = d2.split(' ');
    d2[0]   = d2[0].split('-');
    d2[1]   = d2[1].split(':');
    d2      = d2[0].concat(d2[1]);

    d2 = new Date(d2[0],d2[1],d2[2],d2[3],d2[4],d2[5]);
    d2 = Date.UTC(d2.getFullYear(), d2.getMonth(), d2.getDate(), d2.getHours(), d2.getMinutes(), d2.getSeconds());

    var dDiff = d2 - d1; // calcula a diferenca entre as datas

    var out = {
        'y' : dDiff/1000/60/60/24/30/12,    // calculo para ano
        'm' : dDiff/1000/60/60/24/30,       // calculo para mes
        'd' : dDiff/1000/60/60/24,          // calculo para dia
        'h' : dDiff/1000/60/60,             // calculo para hora
        'i' : dDiff/1000/60,                // calculo para minuto
        's' : dDiff/1000/1                  // calculo para segundo
    };

    out = Math.floor(out[diff]);    // Saida (inteiro do calculo)

    // Retorno
    if(out < 0 && !returnLiteral){
        return out*-1;
    }else{
        return out;
    }
}

betweenDates('2015-11-02 00:00:00', '2015-10-02 23:00:00', 'y') // 0
betweenDates('2015-11-02 00:00:00', '2015-10-02 23:00:00', 'm') // -1
betweenDates('2015-10-02 00:00:00', '2015-11-02 23:00:00', 'm') // 1
betweenDates('2015-10-02 00:00:00', '2015-10-02 23:00:00', 's') // 82800
betweenDates('2015-10-02 00:00:00', '2015-10-02 23:00:00', 'h') // 23
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema no seu código é o mês, que é indexado em zero, mas você está subtraindo do dia. Além disso o resultado da divisão pode retornar um número não esperado, então é necessário arredondar com [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil).

```js
function parseDate(str) { // aceita dia/mes/ano
    var mdy = str.split('/')
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[1] - 1, mdy[0]);
}

function daydiff(first, second) {
    var date1 = parseDate(first);
    var date2 = parseDate(second);
    return Math.ceil((date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + 1;
}

// exibição dos resultados
var pre = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre'));
pre.textContent += '30/09/2014 a 30/09/2014: ';
pre.textContent += daydiff('30/09/2014', '30/09/2014') + ' dia(s)\n';
pre.textContent += '30/09/2014 a 01/10/2014: ';
pre.textContent += daydiff('30/09/2014', '01/10/2014') + ' dia(s)\n';
pre.textContent += '30/09/2014 a 30/10/2014: ';
pre.textContent += daydiff('30/09/2014', '30/10/2014') + ' dia(s)\n';
```